# Arduino Human Infrared Sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, infrared

I started out again with Arduino (beginner), but I wanted to know if I could connect another human infrared sensor like [this](https://www.banggood.com/180-Degree-Human-Infrared-Sensor-Switch-Light-Sensor-Monitoring-Spotlights-Pir-Switch-p-981659.html?) to the Arduino Uno. I know how to connect a simple pir [like this one](https://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-Mini-IR-Pyroelectric-Infrared-PIR-Motion-Human-Body-Sensor-Detector-Module-New-p-49018.html?), but I dont know for sure how to connect the 12V one (if its possible). Guess the red wire goes to a seperate 12V power supply, brown goes to ground and blue then goes to a digital pin on the arduino arduino? I didnt really understand the description that was available for the 12V sensor, so thats why I am asking (I want to be entirely sure before buying).

Thanks

Comment: They're exactly the same - just one is in a fancy box and has a light sensor so it only triggers at night.

Comment: @Majenko But it says it needs 12V So the output pin of the Sensor should be fluctuating in 12V But Arduino Pins are 5V tolerant.

Comment: site says "_N- Blue (zero line), L- Brown (connected FireWire), Output - Red (sensor output lines)_". honestly the colors are meant for AC, but i guess it's been re-purposed... 12v is too high for arduino, use an optocoupler.

Comment: It's impossible to tell quite what the output will be from some pictures and chinglish. It should be a relay but who knows? Banggood never has any datasheets. You will need to dismantle one to find out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Blue - Ground, connect to Arduino GND
Brown - Power, connect to external 12V source.
Red - 12 V output. Connect via a diode to arduino input pin. Enable pullup on arduino pin.

This way when the sensor output is low it will pull the arduino pin low. When the output is high the diode blocks the 12V from frying the arduino while the internal pullup ensures the input pin goes to a safe voltage for a high pin.

Don't put the diode the wrong way around or things will go bang.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKVZb8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be compatible with Arduino with a bit of support. Now the first issue is this that we don't really know that what sensor is this detaily. So we can't really find a datasheet that could say it's pinout or its electrical characteristics. Now assuming those pinouts are similar to those of the any sensor that are **VCC Data Out GND** Then you could probably use it but according to that page it says it needs 12V So according to that Data Out also must be fluctuating with voltage near 12V. So the solution would be to use a voltage divider circuit. Now you could find the resistor values from the Google. I think that setup should be ***Okay***  but I can't tell anything up to you provide us with any data sheet.